# How to move to top part by history.push in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use history.push but this show middle or bottom or top or something of next page.

I wanna make that show top of the next page every time.

please give me advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` in componentDidMount.